# How to get rid of plots under mainplot in Seaborn?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Trying to plot linear regression-plot with Seaborn and I am ending up having this:

[image: first part of the plot]

and under it these empty plots:
[image: first extra (non-needed) plot - second part under main 3 subplots]
[image: second extra (non-needed) plot - second part under main 3 subplots]
[image: third extra (non-needed) plot - second part under main 3 subplots]

I don't need the last 3 small subplots, or at least how to get them plotted correctly, with the main first 3 subplots above?

Here is the code I used:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(12, 15))

for col, ax in zip(['gross_sqft_thousands','land_sqft_thousands','total_units'], axes.flatten()):
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=85)
    ax.set_ylabel(col, fontsize=15)
    sns.jointplot(x="sale_price_millions", y=col, data=clean_df, kind='reg', joint_kws={'line_kws':{'color':'cyan'}}, ax=ax) 

fig.suptitle('Sale Price vs Continuous Variables', position=(.5,1.02), fontsize=20)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

Comment: There is no way to run your code unless you provide the data. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You're using a workaround for the fact that `jointplot` produces its own figure. This workaround has its limitations, namely that the original figures are still created. However, it seems there isn't really any need for a jointplot if you're note interested in the marginal distributions anyways. So why not use a `regplot` instead?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest you're right! It's because I can't change the color of the fitting line. If I use regplot, I won't be able to use joint_kws={'line_kws':{'color':'cyan'}} to change the color of the line, to something which one can see directly over the color of the scatter points.

Comment: Got it! Used regplot with line_kws! Thanks a lot @ImportanceOfBeingErnest